# Como solucionar your branch origin/master have diverged

Tags: git, gitlab

Tengo un problema al traer datos desde un repositorio a mi entorno de desarrollo.
Para traer los cambios desde el repositorio de *gitlab* lo hago mediante un *pull*.

Ahora cada vez que hago un *pull* me dice lo siguiente:

> On branch master
> Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
> and have 20 and 13 different commitys each, respectrivelu
> (use git pull to merge the remote branch into yours)

Al hacer el `git pull` me pide hacer *commits* a ficheros "locales", hago un *commit* and *pull* pero no me hace el *merge*.

¿Cómo puedo unir todo en una sola rama?

De antemano gracias.

**Información complementaria**
**Git pull**

```
usuario@n3310:/var/local/vhosts/dev2.mydominio.eu$ git pull
Auto-merging themes/mydominio/assets/css/theme.css
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in themes/mydominio/assets/css/theme.css
CONFLICT (modify/delete): modules/wkelasticsearch/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Endpoints/index.php deleted in HEAD and modified in 857e02b484e3b8346fc5419886967b2dc9325405. Version 857e02b484e3b8346fc5419886967b2dc9325405 of modules/wkelasticsearch/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Endpoints/index.php left in tree at modules/wkelasticsearch/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Endpoints/index.php~857e02b484e3b8346fc5419886967b2dc9325405.
error: failed to open 'modules/wkelasticsearch/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Endpoints/index.php~857e02b484e3b8346fc5419886967b2dc9325405': Permission denied
```

**Git status**

````
usuario@n3310:/var/local/vhosts/dev2.mydominio.eu$ git status
On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 24 and 14 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   themes/mydominio/assets/css/theme.css

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

**Git log**
```
* 8163bb5a (HEAD -> master) cambios locales ramas bifurcadas
* d8782810 Despues de pull
* 116a7721 Despues de pull
* 4c831a50 previo pull 1648
* a389d4c2 Restaurar commit
* dab90fcb Cambios locales previo merge
* 501cb77e (remoto) cambios locales previo merge
* 2eb72de2 fichero previo commit
* 25ca680c Añadir ficheros para el merge
* 8d0ae440 commit a readme
* 445d6a94 cambios patri
* 84a26273 Cambios Patri
* da045ac0 Install Share and social follow
* fe7a9411 Modulo Wishlist
* e54cdbd4 cotejamiento diferencia product-item-17
* 16e4ed89 correccion tpl merger
* 5e050d7d cambios gitignore
* 49f518c0 actualizacion gitignore
* 80c3ae25 Cambios tema mydominio
* 60d45fc7 Cambios viernes
*   7b272e8c Merge branch 'master' of gldev2.mydominio.eu:dev2/dev2.mydominio.eu
|\
* \   055208b1 Merge branch 'master' of gldev2.mydominio.eu:dev2/dev2.mydominio.eu
|\ \
* \ \   4d633e86 Merge branch 'master' of gldev2.mydominio.eu:dev2/dev2.mydominio.eu
|\ \ \
* | | | f51c3f6e index.tpl
| | | | * 857e02b4 (origin/master) home page changes
| | | | * 526dc591 prueba
| | | | * 2785e382 footer and banner harcoded
| | | | * 37b3b88a Update themes/mydominio/assets/css/theme.css
| | | | * 317ee2d3 modulo blockausserance de la raiz y estilos del tema
| | | | *   0a120d72 Merge branch 'master' of gldev2.mydominio.eu:dev2/dev2.mydominio.eu
| | | | |\
| | | | | * f41e59e4 style upgrade un template of ressurance module
| | | | * |   173b4c65 Merge branch 'master' of gldev2.mydominio.eu:dev2/dev2.mydominio.eu
| | | | |\ \
| | | | | |/
| | | | | * 78857847 Add new file
| | | | | * e4d54577 Update .gitignore
| | | | * | 261de1a7 testing connection
| | | | * | 6358c08f testing the repo conection
| | | | |/
| | | | * 41e95634 products view on carousel
| | | | * fa3d22a9 carousel, footer and styles
| | | |/
| | | *   614c159c (origin/develop) Merge branch 'revert-60784ec8' into 'master'
| | | |\
| | |/ /
| | | * 1e664b77 (origin/revert-60784ec8) Revert "cleaning project, styles guide and carousel changed"
| | |/
| | * 60784ec8 cleaning project, styles guide and carousel changed
```

Cada vez que quiero hacer un pull, me obliga a hacer un commit de cambios locales

Lo que tengo en mi repositorio es lo "correcto" solo quiero que todo lo que hay en el repositorio se ponga encima de todo lo que hay en local

De antemano muchas gracias

***********************************
**Nueva actualizacion**

Despues de arreglar los conflictos, he realizado un commit, un pull para mergear y vuelve a generar los conflictos 
estos son los resultados 

```
usuario@n3310:/var/local/vhosts/dev2.mydomain.eu$ git commit
[master 8715b770] Arreglo conflictos merge
 7 files changed, 158 insertions(+), 175 deletions(-)
 rewrite themes/mydomain/assets/css/theme.css (88%)
 rewrite themes/mydomain/templates/_partials/banner-universes.tpl (96%)
 rewrite themes/mydomain/templates/index.tpl (69%)
 
usuario@n3310:/var/local/vhosts/dev2.mydomain.eu$ git status
On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 25 and 15 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

nothing to commit, working tree clean

usuario@n3310:/var/local/vhosts/dev2.mydomain.eu$ git pull
Auto-merging themes/mydomain/templates/index.tpl
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in themes/mydomain/templates/index.tpl
Auto-merging themes/mydomain/templates/_partials/footer.tpl
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in themes/mydomain/templates/_partials/footer.tpl
CONFLICT (modify/delete): modules/wkelasticsearch/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Endpoints/index.php deleted in HEAD and modified in 83367b9f495d0e8b79f6cd2765162d934c884617. Version 83367b9f495d0e8b79f6cd2765162d934c884617 of modules/wkelasticsearch/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Endpoints/index.php left in tree at modules/wkelasticsearch/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Endpoints/index.php~83367b9f495d0e8b79f6cd2765162d934c884617.
error: failed to open 'modules/wkelasticsearch/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Endpoints/index.php~83367b9f495d0e8b79f6cd2765162d934c884617': Permission denied

usuario@n3310:/var/local/vhosts/dev2.mydomain.eu$ git status
On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 25 and 15 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   themes/mydomain/templates/_partials/footer.tpl
        modified:   themes/mydomain/templates/index.tpl

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```
````

Comment: Podrias colocar el comando que estas ejecutando con la salida completa en la pregunta? Adicionalmente, podrías colocar la salida de este comando? `git log --oneline --graph @ @{u}` (de pronto no completo el log, pero si las partes relevantes de las dos ramas desde por lo menos su última revisión común).

Comment: Y no entiendo lo que quieres decir con que te pide hacer commits a ficheros locales. Coloca la salida de `git pull` completo y de `git status` cuando termina el pull, plis (y el git log que ya dije en el comentario anterior)

Comment: @eftshift0, he puesto el resultado de git log en respuesta ya que aqui no cabe, gracias

Comment: edita la **pregunta** y lo pones ahi. En todo caso, se puede ver que ls ramas están bifurcadas. Creo que necesitamos las salidas de `git pull; git status; git log` en ese orden (el git log como lo puse en el comenario).

Comment: Gracias @eftshift0, ya lo he añadido

Comment: El pull no ha terminado pq tienes conflictos. Resuelvelos, termina la revisión y entonces podrás hacer el push.

Comment: @eftshift0, he editado la pregunta, he realizado el arreglo de conflictos, realizado un commit y al hacer un pull vuelve a generar conflicto, he puesto los resultados por si me puedes echar una mano, gracias

Comment: Bueno.... si te siguen saliendo conflictos al hacer pull es porque hay revisiones nuevas en la rama remota desde que intentaste la última vez.... si te apuras y resuelves los conflictos, deberías poder subir los cambios antes de que otros desarrolladores empujen otras revisiones en la rama.

Comment: @eftshift0, afortunadamente solo estamos 3 en el equipo y he arreglado los errores en cuanto se han ido, persiste el error.  Otra opcion que he intentado es directamente descargar el archivo del repositorio, eliminar el que esta en produccion y subir el del repo, me marca problemas al final de cada fichero me añade un espacio al final o una linea mas en blanco al final

Comment: @eftshift0, finalmente lo he solucionado descargando los ficheros del repo y copiandolos al server.  En el proceso del pull algo pasa que me añade al final del archivo con conflicto un espacio o retorno de línea. No se si sea la mejor solución pero de momento me ha servido. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

**Solucionado**

Gracias a la ayuda de @eftshift0 os pongo como se ha solucionado.

AL hacer un pull, habia conflictos con ficheros los cuales he tenido que solucionar para poder hacer un merge y se pudiese completar el merge.

El problema es que por mas que editara el fichero siempre habia una diferencia al final del fichero, añadia un espacio
Lo que he he hecho es eliminar el fichero, descargarlo del repositorio y copiarlo al server para posteriormente hacer un commit y pull.